# Woff2 fonts gone in cefsharp on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, woff2

Using Cefsharp for Windows Forms (all latest version)...

I added Cefsharp to a new solution and I created this code:

```
    Private _chromeBrowser As ChromiumWebBrowser

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call InitializeChromium()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeChromium()
        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1")
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
        _chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/SelectBox/Overview/Knockout/Light/")
        Me.Controls.Add(_chromeBrowser)
        _chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End Sub
```

The url I use, have some Woff2 fonts in eg. thier selectbox.

If I run the app in Windows 10, I see the dropdown (woff2) fine:

[image]

But if I run the code on my Windows Server 2012R2, the icons are missing:

[image]

If I open Chrome on my Windows Server 2012R2 and open the url, then the arrows are shown. So it is only when using Cefsharp.

Any idea why the woff2 font are not shown in a Cefsharp running on Windows Server 2012R2?

Comment: What version are you using? Are you using WinForms or WPF?  CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers.

Comment: I'm using Cefsharp for Windows Forms ... I've updated my post.

Comment: Please specify the exact version. Latest is relative.

Comment: Please download the CEF Sample application using http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/cef_binary_83.4.4%2Bgbabcf94%2Bchromium-83.0.4103.106_windows32_client.tar.bz2 and test with cefclient.exe --multi-threaded-message-loop --no-sandbox --disable-site-isolation-trials it's likely this is a CEF bug.

Comment: Similar issue https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2858/fonts-not-loading-look-wrong-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was developing in Windows 8. I have updated font-face local to url
and it is okay now.
Ref: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2858/fonts-not-loading-look-wrong-on-windows-7

[solution.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGQMz.png)